# Compare a user selection versus two different benchmarks

Tags: tableau-api

I have a predefined benchmark for each client and would also like to include a user defined benchmark.  So that I can compare a selected clients performance on several metrics versus the predefined benchmark and and a group of clients the user selects, excluding the selected client.

For example using the built in Superstore data, I want to compare a sale person to other sales people in their region (predefined benchmark group) and also compare a sales person to a user selected group of other sales people (user defined benchmark group) for the metrics commission and sales. How can I do this in Tableau?

Comment: Can you reword the question? Sounds like there could be multiple questions in there all potentially with different answers.

Comment: @Andy TAR Sols I've tried to clarify the question please let me know if further explanation is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on this, I have put together a Tableau Public workbook that may help you see how to use Set Actions: https://public.tableau.com/views/CompareItemsSetAction/CompareVsDynamicGroup?:display_count=y&publish=yes&:origin=viz_share_link

I'll try and write this up in the near future as well, but you should be able to deconstruct how this works. There is 1 set and the actions on the dashboard drive it.

Comment: I tried to modify your workbook to my use case I need to be able to have two user defined  action sets, the country and the comparison group of countries and create a table where the columns are country, comparison group and rows are the metrics. How would i modify your workbook to do this?

Comment: Sounds very similar to the example in my sample workbook. Remove the data field from the line chart and convert it to a table. Use Measure Names / Measure Values in the table for your rows of metrics. https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-display-measures-in-a-table/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I suggest you look at using sets. This article from Tableau is very informative and should cover your use cases: https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2018/11/8-ways-bring-powerful-new-comparisons-viz-audiences-set-actions-97207